# Which clipless mountain bike pedals have free float (i.e. no spring recentering)?

Tags: mountain-bike, pedals, clipless, spd

The only mountain bike pedal I've found that doesn't have spring recentering are [Speedplay Frog Pedals](http://www.speedplay.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=home.frog).

I've tried Shimano SPD pedals and Crank Bros Eggbeaters/Candy and both have spring recentering in the angular float. It appears most pedals have a spring or other retention system that increases the tension as you twist your foot away from center until you've unclipped.

Are there any pedals similar to Speedplay X/Zero and Frog for mountain biking that have free float through its full range of angular motion?

Comment: Are you also concerned with lateral float, or only angular float?

Comment: Have you tried the eggbeaters with the cleats the other way around? That should give you 20 degrees before unclipping, and a fair chunk in the middle that's unsprung.

Comment: @Emyr Mainly concerned with angular. Updated question to mention that.

Comment: @alex Yes. Spring centering seems to kick in if I exceed 1 degree and gets stronger as I move further from center.